# Python logging YAML formatting alignment with literal string concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to setup my logging format in Python 3 app using YAML config format. However, I've found myself unable to format it the way I wanted to.

The format uses f-string interpolation to interpret values from the logger. I want to add a literal string to this interpreted value and then align and pad it all.

This is my current config:

```
formatters:
    complex:
        format: '{asctime} {name:<16} [{levelname:^9}] {funcName:16} {message}'
        datefmt: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        style: '{'
```

What I want to do is to append the string `():` to funcName so the result will be eg.

`<somestuff> myfunction():     <somemessage>`

YAML allowes me to use `{funcName:16}():` but that results in

`myFunction          (): <somemessage>`

I have been able to find a way using nesting f-strings when using a simple print function in a random .py file

```py
funcName = "myFunction"
print(f"<somestuff> {'f{funcName}():':16} <somemessage>")
```

This correctly prints the message

`<somestuff> myfunction():     <somemessage>`

But changing the YAML formatter to the same just gives me bunch of errors and doesn't work.

`'{asctime} {name:<16} [{levelname:^9}] {"f{funcName}():":16}  {message}'`

I've also tried to escape the (): symbols by putting them in double curly braces as per f-string specification but that results in errors as well.

Is there any way to join the string literal to the interpreted string?

EDIT: The error given is `ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `field name` (or even `field`) in the PyYAML source, so the ValueError is not coming from an incorrect YAML source. PyYAML normally gives a more identifiable error anyway.

If you do:

```
print("<somestuff> {'f{funcName}():':16} <somemessage>".format())
```

You get the Error:

```
ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
```

And that is what the logging module is trying to do. It doesn't interpret that string as an f-string, it uses `format()` on the string internally, with appropriate arguments.

Comment: That wasn't the problem. I do have it correctly closed in my config file, I just made a mistake while copying it over to stackoverflow. I've fixed it and added the error I am getting, I apologize for my blunder.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I see my misunderstanding now. However, I'm still at loss as to how to achieve my desired string format, if at all possible.

Comment: I once made a [package](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/string_formatter/src/default/) which had a special formatter allowing a single character to be specificied. I am not sure if that can be extended to allow `():` though, and then you would need to provide a special logging formatter as well. (Interesting use case, but I have no time to investigate that right now).

Comment: As I thought, there's no simple way of making it work. Making own formatter is a good solution but unfortunately, not really worth my time for the scale of the project. I'll just have to make do with the current formatting, it's just a small quality of life thing. Thank you for your help.